# how to enable sql usability in new workbook

Tags: sql, excel, vba

Could you please help me how could I ensure that I can use SQL query for an .xlsb file which is bigger than 1 Gb when it is opened by excel (colours, 160 columns, 400K rows)?

Shall I do anything in Excel tools setting? What?

I tried several codes from these topics and I can not use them. I run Excel 2007 on my PC.

Thanks,

Levente

Comment: Do you know how to use sql with a small excel file?

Comment: you ended up with >1 GB in xlsb??? you have bigger problems than tweaking settings. Somewhere you or someone screwed big time.

Comment: Hi, I can write basic scripts in SQL and succeeded to use it in smaller files earlier.

Comment: it is 160Mb in xlsb format, and requires more than a Gb memory when Excel opens it...

Comment: The techniques that work with small files also work with big ones, unless your computer doesn't have the horsepower.

Comment: What shall be enough for an xlsb file with 160 columns, 400K rows and colours? Size is ~160Mb when stored as xlsb, and over 1Gb memory needed when excel opens it....